# minloc function in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran, intrinsics

I want to find location of minimum value of element in 2D array.The array is complex and the first index for a first dimension is zero. However, I want to function searches the array elements with indexes that are larger than zero.Can i make that restriction?
Code is:

```
Program Prvi

Implicit none

Integer,parameter::Ncv=3,Nsa=4
Complex::A(0:Ncv-1,Nsa)

..........
.........
! and after all calculation i want to find location of minimum element

Write(*,*) minloc(abs(A))

Stop
End program Prvi
```

Comment: Is this your alter ego http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683998/using-minloc-function-in-gfortran ?

Comment: No, you can't set minloc to work like that. You can subtract one from the result or write your own search function which always starts from 0..